# Delphi Rio 10.3.3 MapView Marker onDrag returns wrong coordinates

Tags: delphi, draggable, marker

I am trying to build a project which uses Mapview component with a draggable Mapmarker. The problem is that the onMarkerDrag and onMarkerDragEnd events both return the Mapmarker created MapCoordinate and not the dragged one (Marker is Moving normally on the map and Google Maps component shows map without problem - API key is working perfectly).
Here is the code:

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Maps,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Sensors,
  System.Sensors.Components, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MapView1: TMapView;
    LocationSensor1: TLocationSensor;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MapView1MarkerDrag(Marker: TMapMarker);
    procedure MapView1MarkerDragEnd(Marker: TMapMarker);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  System.Permissions, FMX.DialogService;
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  MapDescr: TMapMarkerDescriptor;
  marker: TMapMarker;
  coord: TMapCoordinate;
begin
  coord := TMapCoordinate.Create(42,17);
  MapDescr := TMapMarkerDescriptor.Create(coord, 'Test');
  MapDescr.Draggable := True;
  MapView1.AddMarker(MapDescr);

    {$IF defined(Android)}
      PermissionsService.RequestPermissions
        ([JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)],
        procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>;
          const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
        begin
          if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and
            (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
            { activate or deactivate the location sensor }
            begin
              LocationSensor1.Active := True;
            end
          else
            begin
              LocationSensor1.Active := false;
              TDialogService.ShowMessage('Location permission not granted');
            end;
        end);
      sleep(100);
      {$ENDIF}
      sleep(200);
      {$IF defined(Android)}
      PermissionsService.RequestPermissions
        ([JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS)],
        procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>;
          const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
        begin
          if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and
            (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
            { activate or deactivate the location sensor }
            begin
              LocationSensor1.Active := True;
            end
          else
            begin
              LocationSensor1.Active := false;
              TDialogService.ShowMessage('Location permission not granted');
            end;
        end);
      sleep(100);
      {$ENDIF}


end;

procedure TForm1.MapView1MarkerDrag(Marker: TMapMarker);
begin
  Memo1.BeginUpdate;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Dragging:'+FloatToStr(Marker.Descriptor.Position.Latitude)+'-'+FloatToStr(Marker.Descriptor.Position.Longitude));
  Memo1.EndUpdate;
end;

procedure TForm1.MapView1MarkerDragEnd(Marker: TMapMarker);
begin
  Memo1.BeginUpdate;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('End:'+FloatToStr(Marker.Descriptor.Position.Latitude)+'-'+FloatToStr(Marker.Descriptor.Position.Longitude));
  Memo1.EndUpdate;
end;

end.
```

After executing code on Android mobile device both event procedures returns: 42,17.
I have built the app using SDK 25.2.5 32bit and 26.1.1 32bit with the same result, i have also tried adding to manifest xml file the following:

```
<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

without any success.
In target platforms libraries i use the default: com-google-android-gms.play-services-maps.16.1.0.dex.jar.
Thanks in advance.